# количество подписчиков у публичной Страницы в Facebook по api

Tags: php, facebook-api

как получить количество подписчиков у публичной Страницы в Facebook по api?
В данной [документации](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/page) ничего не нашел.
Может у кого есть какие идеи, кроме обычного парсера страницы? или я просто не внимателен и не увидел в документации?

Answer (score 1):

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11
  /id 
    /friends 
    &access_token=user-access-token
```

в ответ придет

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Julia Goulia",
      "id": "julia's-user-id"
    },
    {
      "name": "Steven Even",
      "id": "steven's-user-id"
    }
        ],
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 156
  }
}
```

Comment: познавательно, но мне достаточно ссылку на документацию, а там уже я разберусь. Например по вашему примеру, вот [документация](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends). Да и я спрашивал про публичные страницы, а не про личных подписчиков

Comment: ты поставил минус моему вопросу, дал неправильный ответ и слился? по моему ты не прав) ощущение что ты как затычка, лишь бы что нибудь написать, для кармы, а остальное не важно